# CDI with JEE: how handle dependency injection in the backend without EJB

Tags: rest, jax-rs, ejb, cdi

I'm working on a REST api with Java, using JAX-RS, EJB, JPA and JasperReports, basically the API call a oracle function that return an id, with that id i make a select and generate reports with Jasper Reports, then i send the report as a response, works fine.

But, i have some questions if i should use or not use EJB, because i dont see why i should use EJB in this case, since the oracle function have commit inside of it, if something goes wrong, the rollback triggered by the EJB will not do nothing right? Also, the select that generates the report is simple, just one table, and i saw some articles saying that if you do just a select theres no need for using EJB to control the transaction.

Also, how to use CDI in this case? @Named in the classes and @Inject in the fields? I have some coworkers saying that @Named should be used just with JSF, but i'm a junior, seeking for the truth about this, after researching a lot i still dont know how to handle this, i apreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: I think that you're imagining there is some cost to using an EJB when there is not. You're think of it as a transaction manager when it is also a pool-able, monitor-able, reuse-able object. The same cannot be said about CDI beans (at this point in time) without adding complexity to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Do I need EJBs for transactions?**

If you are using JEE-7+ then you can use @Transactional for your CDI Beans instead of EJB-Beans with @Stateless and @TransactionManagement and @TransactionAttribute. @Transactional provides the same properties as @TransactionAttribute and makes any CDI Bean transactional without the need for an EJB Container. All of these approaches require JPA to be used, which for a simple single query is maybe an overkill.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html

**What can I use instead of EJBs and @Transactional?**

If you don't need/want to use an EntityManager, then just use plain JDBC.

**What does @Named do?**

@Named makes CDI Beans accessible to Java-EL via their defined name, or if no one is defined then via their simple class name. You can also use @Named to distinguish between implementations, but I think CDI Qualifiers are more suitable to achieve that. So, if you don't need it, then don't annotate it.

**How to provide CDI Beans to other CDI Beans?**

In my opinion CDI Beans should be injected via Fields and not constructor arguments. Injection in constructor arguments is done because of testability, so you can test your beans without using CDI, which these days is not that hard to achieve anymore.

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html